How can I represent DataFrame in StaticCompiler?
I want to compile some code with help of StaticCompiler. I want to use StaticCompiler to produce small executable binaries. The program shall represent float numbers, integer numbers and strings in a DataFrame. Do you know, how to do this, or what similar representation could work with StaticCompiler?
I run StaticCompiler on Windows. I adapted StaticCompiler to Windows, which seems to work. But I cannot be sure whether some of the errors (see below) are windows-specific.
As a first step I want to represent the float numbers, integer numbers and strings in an array. However, many things don't work for StaticCompiler, because GC-tracked allocations are not allowed.
I tried MallocArray or MallocMatrix on an union of Int64, Float64 and MallocString, but this does not work.
Now I used a MallocArray on Int64. Strings would be coded as integer numbers. So I implemented coding functions and decoding functions.
This requires converting an UInt8 to an Int. (The type of a charackter in a MallocString in StaticCompiler is UInt8. E.g. m"ABC"[2] is 0x42 and is of type UInt8.) However, applying Int() results in an error (although Int() in a separate function works fine).
Similarly, when using a MallocArray on Float64, I additionally need Int() to decode float numbers (and strings) which does not work.
This is the code.
using StaticTools, StaticCompiler

mutable struct Df
  table::MallocArray{Int64}
  number_of_rows::Int64
  number_of_columns::Int64

  function Df(number_of_rows::Int64,number_of_columns::Int64)
    table = MallocArray{Int64}(undef,number_of_rows*number_of_columns)
    new(table,number_of_rows,number_of_columns)
  end

end

function set_value(df::Df,row_num::Int64,column_num::Int64,str::MallocString)
  idx = (row_num-1) * df.number_of_columns + column_num
  df.table[idx] = str2num(str)
end

function str2num(str::MallocString)::Int64
  len = length(str)
  num = 0
  for i in 1:len
    num += (Int(str[i])-64) * 26 ^ (len-i)
  end
  num 
end

function f()
  df = Df(2,3)  
  set_value(df,1,1,m"A")
  0
end

f()
compile_executable(f, (), "C:\\jul\\staticcompiler")


It results in
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: julia.new_gc_frame

obviously a linking error (?), and some warnings regarding the generated LLVM IR:
Warning: Found pointer references to julia data
¦   llvm instruction = store {}* inttoptr (i64 3221089733040 to {}*), {}** %28, align 8
¦   name = Symbol("")
¦   file = Symbol("")
¦   line = -1
¦   fromC = true
¦   inlined = false
+ @ StaticCompiler C:\Users\T460\.julia\packages\StaticCompiler\RM4Pv\src\pointer_warning.jl:59
+ Warning: LLVM function generated warnings due to raw pointers embedded in the code. This will likely cause errors or undefined behaviour.
¦   func =
¦    define internal fastcc void @julia_set_value_915({}* noundef nonnull align 8 dereferenceable(24) %0, i64 signext %1, i64 signext %2, [2 x i64]* nocapture noundef nonnull readonly align 8 dereferenceable(16) %3) unnamed_addr {
¦    top:
¦      %4 = alloca [2 x {}*], align 8
¦      %gcframe = call {}** @julia.new_gc_frame(i32 1)
¦      call void @julia.push_gc_frame({}** nonnull %gcframe, i32 1)
¦      %5 = bitcast {}* %0 to i8*
¦      %6 = getelementptr inbounds i8, i8* %5, i64 16
¦      %7 = bitcast i8* %6 to i64*
¦      %8 = load i64, i64* %7, align 8, !tbaa !2, !alias.scope !8, !noalias !11
¦      %9 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %3, i64 0, i64 1
¦      %unbox = load i64, i64* %9, align 8, !tbaa !16, !alias.scope !18, !noalias !19
¦      %10 = add i64 %unbox, -1
¦      %11 = call i64 @llvm.smax.i64(i64 %10, i64 0)
¦      %12 = icmp slt i64 %10, 1
¦      br i1 %12, label %L52, label %L23.preheader
¦    
¦    L23.preheader:                                    ; preds = %top
¦      %13 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %3, i64 0, i64 0
¦      %bitcast = load i64, i64* %13, align 8, !tbaa !16, !alias.scope !18, !noalias !19
¦      %14 = inttoptr i64 %bitcast to i8*
¦      br label %L23

etc.
What do these errors mean? What goes on there?
How could I get it work?
